# Rails - assert_redirect_to with an unknow parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I build a Rails application with a feature who can serve a random recipe:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

    # GET /recipes/shuffle
    # get a random recipe and redirect user on this
    def shuffle
        offset = rand Recipe.count
        random  = Recipe.offset(offset).first
        redirect_to recipe_path random
    end

end
```

It work great but I want to build a test on this route

```
require 'test_helper'

class RecipesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should be redirect to a random recipe path" do
    get :shuffle
    assert_redirected_to(  controller: "recipes", action: "show"  ) 
  end

end
```

But in fact it doesn't work because I get this error message:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipes"}

Here my *route.rb*:

```
RaspberryCook::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :recipes, :only => [:index, :new , :create , :destroy , :edit]
  get     'recipes/:id' ,         to: 'recipes#show', id: /[0-9]+/
  patch  'recipes/:id' ,         to: 'recipes#update', id: /[0-9]+/
  get    'recipes/shuffle' ,      to: 'recipes#shuffle'
  post    'recipes/import' ,      to: 'recipes#import'

end
```

So how can I build my test like "Should get a random recipe with an unknown ID"?

Comment: Did you define the corresponding route in `routes.rb`? What does your `routes.rb` looks like?

Comment: @Rashmirathi, I edited my post & I added my *route.rb*

Comment: maybe pass an id in your `asset_redirected_to`

Comment: @maxpleaner, but I don't know what is the id genrated by `offset = rand Recipe.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself and I used a simple regex matcher like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class RecipesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should be redirect to a random recipe path" do
    get :shuffle
    assert_redirected_to %r(/recipes/[0-9]+)
  end

end
```

Easy but it does the job!

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have a variable generated inside your controller method that you have no way to access through the tests.

It's a common requirement to refer to internal variables of methods being tested, and the comment of a 'mock' or 'stub' is helpful.

Here, you could stub the result of the `rand` call to return a predetermined number. This can all be done in the test case:

```
id = 1
expect(Kernel).to receive(:rand).with(Recipe.count).and_return(id)
get :shuffle
assert_redirected_to(controller: "recipes", action: "show", id: id)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'expect' for #<RecipesControllerTest:0x00000005e4e328>` (because I don't use **rspec**? )

Comment: Yes, it's because youre not using rspEc. You can probably do mocks in whatever's testing library you're using too